# How can ı get usernames with flutter in firestore

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I got the user email but ı can't get usernames how can ı do that ?

```
Future<User?> createUser(String name, String email, String password) async {
  final user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(    
                               email: email, password: password, );
  _firestore
    .collection("User")
    .doc(user.user!.uid)
    .set({'userName' : name, 'email' : email});

  return user.user;
}
```

and how ı write this username in screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're doing it correctly already, just fetch it back from Firestore; you already got the unique UID from the **createUserWithEmailAndPassword** and sent it to the collection called **User**, creating a unique document for the associated logged in user.

Just do:

```dart
DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(user.user!.uid).get();
Map<String, dynamic> docData = userDoc.data();
var userName = docData['userName'];
```

Then you should be good.